# Retrieving a jQuery autocompleted field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I am using the jQuery autocomplete plugin and have wired up an input field to retrieve values from a back end database as text is entered which can then be selected.
I then have a second input field that I have wired up in a similar way however I want to pass in the first input field's value as a querystring parameter in the autocomplete ajax call so that the autocomplete results can be filtered.
I have tried using the .val() method of the first input field but this always seems to return an empty string unless I allow the form to postback. I have also tried just using getElementById('xxx').value but this returns a null value.
Is there any way I can retrieve the dynamic value selected in the first field so I can pass it into my jQuery ajax call to the server?
Code below with some removed for brevity:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Make").autocomplete('/MyController/AutoCompleteMake', {
                dataType: 'json',
                parse: function(data) {
                    var rows = new Array();
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        rows[i] = { data: data[i], value: data[i], result: data[i] };
                    }
                    return rows;
                },
                formatItem: function(row) {
                    return row;
                },
                delay: 40
            });

            $("#Range").autocomplete('/MyController/AutoCompleteRange?Make=' + $('input[name=Make]').val(), {
                same as above .......
            });
        });
  </script>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="Make">Make:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Make") %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Make", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Range">Range:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Range") %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Range", "*") %>
        </p>
<% } %>
```

It is the $('input[name=Make]').val() part that is alway return empty value even if one has been selected.

I have only just started working with jQuery and MVC so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the extraParams function:

```
$("#Make").autocomplete(url, {
   extraParams: {
       yourValue: function() { return $("input[name=Make]").val(); }
   }
});
```

This will then be passed through in the HttpContext to your target.

This can be pulled out as follows:

```
string valueToUse = context.Request.QueryString["yourValue"];
```

From the jQuery AutoComplete [Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete):

> Often one autocompleted field depends
>   on the value of another field. In that
>   case, the extraParams option can
>   provide the necessary dynamic
>   parameter

Your current code doesn't work as you're building up a static string. You need to use a function that will dynamically return the value of the input field you're interested in.

Comment: +1, you are right, I completely and disastrously misunderstood.

Comment: No worries Karim :) Happens to the best of us!

Comment: Spot on. This has been driving me up the wall for a couple of hours. Cheers.

Comment: Just to add, for anyone else new to asp.net mvc like me, that you can reference the querystring value in the controllers action method signature as a parameter instead of retrieving it in the body of the method i.e. public JsonResult AutoCompleteRange(string q, string Make)